# Get contact version return null 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to get contact version for each contacts in my phone,

but some contacts return contact-version null in 'kitkat'.

```
private String getContactVersion(String id)
{
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.VERSION };
    String selection = ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + " = '" + id + "'";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnVersion = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.VERSION);
    String version = cursor.getString(columnVersion);
    cursor.close();
    return version;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

> Version number that is updated whenever this row or its related data changes. This field can be used for optimistic locking of a raw contact.

So it can be `null` actually. "null" means the contact has not been changed.

Additionally "version" column is not an integer. You should get it like below

```
int columnVersion = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.VERSION);
String version = cursor.getInt(columnVersion);
```

Comment: Other contacts returned 2 and more than 2 for the version-number,
I changed line "String version = cursor.getInt(columnVersion);"
but still returned null.

Comment: Version means something has changed in that contact since the beginning. This way Contact Sync system understand the changes and send the new data to Google Contacts backup. If it is null, this means nothing changed.